# Python: How to add a zero after every digit in a number for numbers in list to create a new list

Tags: python

Background: I am trying out doing a fun little monthly computational math puzzle.

I am at a stage that I have a list comprised of binary numbers and I am looking to write a python program that takes all the numbers in the list and appends a zero behind each digit and makes a new list.

1--> 10, 101---> 100010, 10---->1000.

Answer (score 2):

There are more efficient ways, but I just don't feel like thinking, so here it is, it adds 0 using for loop add it to list, then join all the elements from the list

```
while True:
    ff = input("input disits: ")
    ff2 = []
    for i in ff:
        ff2.append(i+'0')
    print(''.join(ff2))
```

Or another way is adding string

```
while True:
    ff = input("input disits: ")
    ff2 = ''
    for i in ff:
        ff2 += i+'0'
    print(ff2)
```

Want int answer? do `print(int(''.join(ff2)))` or `print(int(ff2))`

or

```
while True:
    print(int(''.join([i+'0' for i in input("input disits: ")])))
```

Answer (score 1):

##### string approach

This is easily achieved using strings:

```
def add0(n):
    s = str(n)
    return '0'.join(list(s))+'0'

add0(101)
```

Output: `100010`

##### numerical approach

You need to play with `divmod` and powers of ten

```
def add0(n):
    out = 0
    exp = 0
    while n>0:
        n,r = divmod(n,10)
        out += 10**(2*exp+1)*r
        exp += 1
    return out

add0(12345)
# 1020304050
```

Comment: That's good. An alternative expression: `''.join(d + '0' for d in str(n))`.

Comment: @Jerry101 that was my initial idea, but I liked the fact that `join` can replace the loop. I also added a numerical solution ;)

Comment: Why explicitly create a list? Tried with and without in my benchmark, was equally fast.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way for me was:

```
list = [1, 0]
new_list = []

for i in list:
    new_list.append(i)
    new_list.append(0)
   
print(list)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

A fun more mathy way: Interpret in base 4, multiply by 2, format back to base 2:

```
for s in '1', '101', '10':
    t = f'{int(s, 4) * 2:b}'
    print(s, '->', t)
```

Output:

```
1 -> 10
101 -> 100010
10 -> 1000
```

A little benchmark with a million-bits number:

```
  4.8 ms  rebase
 50.5 ms  translate
 16.5 ms  join
124.6 ms  add
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHNbsMgDL7nKXypgBVFybJKVaQ8S0QW2JgKREAOU9VnzwxUabXNJzDfn83yHT@d7c6L3zblnYGojdQRtFmcj@DlIkWsqlkqPE8iSBpYXwGWl3H1FhS5ahtp4PDG4AVe@@lGCj56YcNFxD@UUD@ers7PlDSE9UCahvCM@68yrs24tiE3Vjy@nLa/5VGtvvfhmG4FKuZ5R0YYgJB8VM7DDBpT9bt3hOOAzUJ@UsZFqNW@B2SXZfDHkDxn4cmmqhIixcSFnJpUSESfMfkg4UPS7p4ktZNmesnazykGMDhG@QN6EWaaRZ9ROAgHu5pJ@qFlbKcsPv0FOZzqVoEJQOAANGKKVnbISNR6HK0wchwLqzDYtv0A)):

```
from timeit import repeat

def rebase(s):
    return f'{int(s, 4) * 2:b}'

def translate(s):
    return s.translate({ord('0'): '00',
                        ord('1'): '10'})

def join(s):
    return '0'.join(s) + '0'

def add(s):
    t = ''
    for d in s:
        t += d + '0'
    return t

funcs = rebase, translate, join, add

s = '10' * 500000

for _ in range(3):
    for func in funcs:
        t = min(repeat(lambda: func(s), number=1))
        print('%5.1f ms ' % (t * 1e3), func.__name__)
    print()
```